# Cannot redeclare class DB_Error in C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php on line 974

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I was just playing around with setting up my new site with a register and login system, when i refreshed this happened. I did not touch that file! (C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php). I checked the file for errors, and the only thing i see on line 974 is a opening curly bracket. I even tried downloading a new DB.php file from pear.php.net, same error. I know the error means that there is two of the same classes, and it doesnt like that, but as far as i can see (ctrl+f search for class DB_Error) there is only one.. Tried looking the error up, but couldnt find anything.... Any help would be very appreciated, as i am new to all this stuff! (: Thanks!

Comment: You are including DB.php more than one time

Comment: Where? Im new to all of this, sorry.. I have no idea where this error occured. I never included that class in any of my htdocs...

Comment: require 'DB.php' to require_once 'DB.php'
or if
inlude 'DB.php' to include_once 'DB.php'

Comment: @user3753614 Don't know which register and login system you are using but I suggest Check your index.php file or header.php file if exists

Comment: I already checked all my files through a thousand times, including index.php and all my include files. I also checked functions.php... Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: Forgot to tag you.. As you might have noticed im also new to this site... @ThinkDifferent

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out where `DB.php` gets included the first and the second time.

Using xdebug to get a function trace is an easy way to determine that. Install xdebug, then put a line

```
xdebug_start_trace('C:\trace.xt');
```

at the beginning of your `index.php` file.

After reloading your browser and thus reproducing the error, open the trace file with a text editor and look for `DB.php`. It will show you where the file gets included.